# Animate box-shadow

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate box-shadow on user input like the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes input-shadow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #373737;
    }
}

@keyframes input-shadow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #373737;
    }
}

.form__element:focus {
    -webkit-animation:input-shadow ease-in-out 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:input-shadow ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

I want to make it work like in bootstrap inputs, but using keyframes.

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't animate `box-shadow` - you'll get lots of jank (dropped frames) due to repaints. Instead add a pseudo shadow using `::after` and animate the `transform` and `opacity` properties on that. Here is a good tutorial for the technique: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it loop to `infinite` and reset the status to initial state at `100%` in your `@keyframes` animation.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes input-shadow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #373737;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
  }

@keyframes input-shadow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #373737;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
 }
.form__element:focus {
    -webkit-animation:input-shadow ease-in-out 1s infinite;
    animation:input-shadow ease-in-out 1s infinite;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/R2F4W/ (removed :focus to trigger without clicking)

Comment: @AymanJitan That was the intention to show the animation - for focus just add :focus back (read my comment near link). Here's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/R2F4W/1/